# How to migrate data from 2 different tables using one by one rows

Tags: sql-server

I want to migrate data from the doctor and lawyer table to the user table.

Here's my doctor table:

```
Name     Age  City
---------------------
pavan    27   Delhi
Kishor   29   Delhi
pavan    30   Delhi
```

Here is my lawyer table

```
Name     Age  City
---------------------
pavan    35   Delhi
Kishor   45   Delhi
pavan    55   Mumbai
```

I want to insert data from the doctor and lawyer table into the user table which has these columns:

```
Name    Age    Active
```

Now I want that there should be only one active name.

Rest all duplicate entries should be marked inactive (active = 0)

this is what my expected result should look like in the user table

```
Name     Age  Active
---------------------
pavan    27   1
Kishor   29   1
pavan    30   0
pavan    35   0
kishor   45   0
pavan    55   0
```

I tried this query, but it didn't work:

```
INSERT INTO User (name, age, active)
    SELECT 
        name, age,
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM User u WHERE u.name = name) 
                THEN 0 
                ELSE 1 
        END
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you decide which is active which is not?

Comment: if I got the duplicate entry in the user table then it should be set as 0.
one way i can think is to check every time on user table by name but it's possibe only when i can select and insert rows one by one only. or by making use cte but not sure how can i do that on 2 tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CTE` & `ROW_NUMBER` with condition to set `active` column value. Try like below.

```
;WITH AllUser AS (
    SELECT name, age FROM doctor
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, age FROM lawyer
)
INSERT INTO User (name, age, active)
SELECT name, age, IIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) = 1, 1, 0)
FROM AllUser
```